# Which is the correct way to use an ALS model in production with new data?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, production, recommendation-engine

Suppose we have trained Spark ALS model on some (current) amount of data:

```
val als = new ALS()
    .setMaxIter(maxIterations)
    ...
val alsModel = als.fit(trainData)
```

Than we can apply it to some data:

```
alsModel.setColdStartStrategy("drop")
val dfPredictions = alsModel.transform(testData)
val dfRecommendations = alsModel.recommendForAllUsers(10)
```

But in my situation data incomes every day in large portions. New users, products and ratings incomes continuously.

What is the best way to handle new incoming data? Retrain model every `N` days?

Comment: please read this QA : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/should-a-model-be-re-trained-if-new-observations-are-available

Comment: @RemisHaroon, thanks. There are some useful ideas in that thread.